# Can't open index.php by default with nginx

Tags: nginx

What's wrong with my server definition? If I try to access to "www.testing.com" I get a binary to download instead of the index.php, instead if I try to access to "testing.com" I get the index.php.

I already tried to set servername to:

```
servername testing.com;
servername testing.com www.testing.com;
servername testing.com www.testing.com *.testing.com;
```

Same behavior: I can't get index.php with "www.testing.com", just with "testing.com".
(off course testing.com is not mine is just for example).

```
    user              nginx;
    worker_processes  4;
    error_log         /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid               /var/run/nginx.pid;

    events {
         worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
         include      /etc/nginx/mime.types;
         default_type  text/plain;

         log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                            '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                            '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

         access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

         fastcgi_intercept_errors    on;
         sendfile                    on;
         keepalive_timeout           65;
         gzip                        on;
         index                       index.php index.html index.htm;

         server {
              listen 80;
              server_name www.testing.com;
              root /home/vhosts/testing;

              location / {
                  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php index.php;
              }

        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
                  expires max;
                  add_header Pragma public;
                  add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
              }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                 try_files $uri =404;
                 include fastcgi.conf;
                 fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
              }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 24):

first you need to check your php-fpm settings (maybe you using socket connection instead of port in your php-fpm configuration) and add index by default in your location "/"

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: Did not work. browser still tries to download the file (did *nginx* restart)

Comment: I was missing this one in try_files **$uri/**

Answer (score 10):

Add `fastcgi_index  index.php;` in `location ~* \.php$`:

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check so fpm is running on `127.0.0.1:9000`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files $uri =404;
     include fastcgi.conf;
     fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

also log error and check:

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  debug;
```

For a sample configuration check:
https://github.com/rtCamp/easyengine/blob/master/conf/nginx/singlesite/basic.conf

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

```
location = / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

The whole location config with proxy is:

```
location = / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can have more than one servername line, it will set up a VHOST on all of them.