# Open index.php with 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, nginx

I use `nginx 1.10.1, PHP 5.4.16 (fpm-fcgi)`.

My files' location is `/usr/share/nginx/html/lab/`. In this dir, there are multiple `.php` files, include `index.php`.

If I put a `index.html` file in this dir, I can see index.html's content from `http://192.168.201.210:8024/lab/` correctly. But If I delete `index.html` file, I can only get `403 Forbidden`.

My `php-fam` works well, and I saw a lot of solutions not works for me:

[Can't open index.php by default with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002245/cant-open-index-php-by-default-with-nginx)

https://serversforhackers.com/video/php-fpm-configuration-the-listen-directive

This is my nginx's configuration file:

```
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen       8024; # default_server;
        # listen       [::]:8024 ipv6only=on default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {

        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {

        location ~* \.php$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            index index.php index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need an index directive(`index index.php`) in your catch all `location /`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the reason: I have another django app listening in the same port - 8024. If I remove the django app's configuration file or modify nginx's configuration file to

```
listen       8024 default_server;
```

then, I can access index.php well. But I cannot access my django app at the same port any more.

Here has a very good tutorial for configuring php in nginx: [PHP FastCGI Example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/)

Answer (score 0):

you can check your log file to get some info
`tail -n 50 /var/log/nginx/access.log`

and do you know about 403,did the php-fpm get right to access web path,
like `chmod 755 -R /usr/share/nginx/html/lab/`

Comment: There is no access.log, I still surprise. Even if I give `777` permission for all files, it still not work. If I access `http://192.168.201.210:8024/lab/index.php` directly, I can download this file, but I cannot see it in browser.